# HashMap string key

Tags: java, android

I have a bug in my Android app and I can't find what's wrong, there is something that I think is problematic and I need your help that.

I have the following HashMap

```
HashMap<String, String> numbers = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

and I'm inserting data into it like so,

```
numbers.put("1", "one" );
numbers.put("2", "two" );
```

Then I search it like this,

```
numbers.get("1");
```

is this correct? please note that the above is working fine except sometimes I see weird behavior as I mentioned earlier

Update, I forgot to add the " in the put.

Comment: Explain what you mean by weird behavior.

Comment: how is your code even compiling?

Comment: How you could put an int in a Map with String?

Comment: that weird behaviour should be something else other than realted to this map. Debug it.

Comment: After the update of your question: What exactly is wrong? What error do you get? What is the expected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

No, that won't work.  You should be putting and getting with the same type of keys.

Perhaps you meant

```
 numbers.put("1", "one");
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have a map of string to string, it should look like this:

```
numbers.put("1", "one" );
numbers.put("2", "two" );
```

Then I search it like this,

```
numbers.get("1");
```

You forgot the quotes around the keys of the map.

Answer (score 0):

1) I think your code is:

```
numbers.put(String.valueOf(1), "one" );
```

2) Maybe that you don't execute `numbers.get("1");` at runtime, but something like this:

```
numbers.get("1 "); // key with space
```

So i suggest to debug your code or try:

```
numbers.get(myKeyString.trim());
```

Comment: That's a good thought.  If the numeric strings are coming from a UI, then it may be possible for them to contain leading or trailing whitespace.  That should be easy to test, too.